# newsmap.jp style

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to make a website like http://newsmap.jp, Is there is any plugin that can help in the UI of the map?

Notice that there is no empty spaces in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) plugin. Just call it directly on your container:

```
$('#container').masonry({
    itemSelector : '.itemsClassName',
    columnWidth : 240 // or whatever
});
```

There many more options, as outlined [in the documentation](http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/options.html).

Comment: Will this make a prefect fit of the cells ?

Comment: @MahmoudAbdElaziz - Yes. Play around with the options to get it exactly the way you want it.

Answer (score 0):

That was a treemap graph, http://jstreemap.com/, and https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/treemap